# How can I pass a List of Ids as a parameter using an ActionFunction?

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

Here's what I have so far.

**Controller**

```
public Id[] SelectedIds {get;set;}
public void TestAction()
{
    system.debug(SelectedIds);
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:outputpanel id="r"></apex:outputpanel>
<apex:actionfunction name="UpdateSelected" action="{!TestAction}" rerender="r"> 
    <apex:param name="ids" value="" assignTo="{!SelectedIds}" /> 
</apex:actionfunction>
```

**JavaScript**

```
UpdateSelected(['a1we00000004EXAAA2','a1we00000004EXBAA2']);
```

**Result**

Invalid conversion from runtime type String to LIST
Error is in expression '{!SelectedIds}' in component  in component

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you cant send a list using **actionfunction**.
To pass a list to controller you can consider using **Remoting**(Stateless).

If you want to send a list of Ids you can always send a csv formatted string using js
Something like

```
<script>
    UpdateSelected('a1we00000004EXAAA2,a1we00000004EXBAA2');
</script>
<apex:actionfunction name="UpdateSelected" action="{!TestAction}" rerender="r"> 
    <apex:param name="ids" value="" assignTo="{!SelectedIds}" /> 
</apex:actionfunction>
```

and in the controller method you can split the string into list by

**Example :**

```
public String SelectedIds{get;set;}
public void TestAction(){
 List<String> allIds = SelectedIds.split(',');
}
```

Comment: Didn't realize that it wasn't even possible. Thanks!