# How to pass String List values to Controller using apex:actionFunction?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am not able to pass String List to Apex Controller using the apex:actionFunction.

Here is the complete code:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!methodOne}"
    name="methodOneJS" reRender="panelOne">
    <apex:param name="recordId" assignTo="{!selRecId}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<Script>
    methodOneJS('003jXXX000APTqu');
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public List<String> recordId{get;set;}
```

Comment: Finally used the solution from this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/how-can-i-pass-a-list-of-ids-as-a-parameter-using-an-actionfunction

Answer (score 1):

I believe the type attribute on  tag won't support list as a value. You have to specify using array-notation.

```
<apex:attribute name="recId"
    description="Id"
    type="String[]" required="true" assignTo="{!recordId}" />
```

Comment: Tried this already..but it throws same kind of error: `Type mismatch for <apex:attribute assignTo>. Value binding to a property of type String is required, property specified (recordId) is of type List<String>. `

Comment: You are correct. It is working for attribute, I am having issue in sending from actionFunction.

Answer (score 1):

```
apex:attribute name="recId" description="List of Id" type="String[]" 
           required="true" assignTo="{!recordId}"
```

--This should work because I just replicated the same in my dev org.

Comment: Datatype in the controller is `List<String>` ?

Comment: Yes sir exactly like yours. Dont know why cant you save. Can you try again. Or plz post full vf code.

Comment: thanks for the reply but just one question did you overwrite the get or set properties?

Comment: I didnt do anything except writing the way you did. List<string>recordid{get;set;}

Comment: I think i confused everybody. I am having trouble with passing values from `actionFunction` not the `attribute`. However I edited my question, Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

if you are unable to use assignTo than don't use it. Simply write:
apex:param name="recordId" name = "myparam" value=""

and in your controller method:
String myparam = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('myparam');
system.debug('myparma is: '+myparam); --> will give the value you passed from JS.

Question - Why are you anyways assigning the record Id to a list?

Comment: I used the solution from this answer, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/how-can-i-pass-a-list-of-ids-as-a-parameter-using-an-actionfunction as I am also passing Ids.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a list. You will have to send one by one as a string and then get that from the pagereference map, like I wrote earlier. Or you can also adopt the way in the link you have provided just now.

Comment: I am using like mentioned in the link. Thanks all for your help